# Why does IIS 7.5 construct a page multiple times

Tags: asp.net, spring, iis-7.5, integrated-pipeline-mode, northwind

I admit that I've already posted a question about the phenomenon I'm observing, but after some more research I'm coming at it here from a slightly different angle, and tagging it differently:

I have a page -- **WorkflowDetail.aspx** -- backed by a class file -- **WorkFlowDetail.aspx.vb**.  That class inherits from **BaseClass1** that inherits from **Spring.Web.UI.Page** (**BaseClass1** has no associated ASPX, just some common properties and methods).

I set a breakpoint in **WorkFlowDetail**'s *New()* method. I find that when I bring the page up in my browser the constructor is run several times.  I'd love to know who's running it and why, but the stack only shows "**[External Code]**".

This would be no more than idle curiosity, or at most a minor annoyance, were I not trying to have **Spring** inject a DAO property into the page.  What happens is that **Spring** does the injection (and one can see all the **Spring** methods on the stack when the debugger stops in *New()*), but then a new copy of the page is created by "**[External Code]**" so that when it gets around to accessing the DAO property it's *null*, because this is a different instance of the page than that into which the property was injected.

This is all happening with **IIS 7.5 Integrated** and a **Web Application** built in **VS2010** targeting **.NET 4.0**.  Setting a similar breakpoint in a page of **Spring**'s **Northwind** example, which is a **Web Site** targeting **.NET 3.5**, it gets hit when **Spring** instantiates the page, and that's it.

Can someone tell me what's causing these extra instantiations, or how I can find out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with the way we were setting the DataSources of our **Telerik RadGrid** controls.  We were assigning them in the ASP code, which caused the **Telerik** code to re-instantiate the page for each assignment (you'll forgive me for not going into the details of why **Telerik** does this).

We got around it by using the controls' **OnNeedDataSource** event to have the DataSources set later on.